# How To "Add New Item" On Quick Launch & Refresh Page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, quick-launch

On a SharePoint 2010 site how can I create an "Add New Item" link to the quick launch that will refresh the parent page when the new item is submitted?

I have used the following snippet to create the link:

```
JavaScript:var options=SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.url='http :// someurl.somedomain.com';
options.height = 400;
void(SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options))
```

but this does not refresh the parent page.  So when the end-user submits their item they don't see the new item in the list.

Comment: You would need a callback function to refresh the page.  How to do that in a quick launch link, I do not know. Here's info on modal [callbacks](http://www.ashokraja.me/articles/How-to-redirect-reload-or-refresh-a-page-after-closing-the-SharePoint-2013-Modal-Popup-Dialog)

Answer (score 0):

This would refresh the page if the parent was closed via a submit button and not by clicking on the 'X'.  Clicking on the 'X' would not refresh the page.

```
var options=SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.url='';
options.height = 400;
options.dialogReturnValueCallback = function(dialogResult) {SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(dialogResult)};
void(SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options));
```